# Convert getElementsByTagName to get hidden input fields

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use an alternative to getElementsByTagName and get get my values in my script the same as before but as hidden input fields instead. Notice that in my list item I have custom html tags. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Right Now I have this:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="my-search-widget" class="effects-list">
   <li query="New York, NY" rsp="5555" leadto="email@email.com"></li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
let e = document.getElementsByTagName("my-search-widget");
0 == e.length && (e = document.getElementById("my-search-widget").getElementsByTagName("li"));
for (let t = 0; t < e.length; t++) {
    let n = e.item(t),
        r = this.defaultOptions;
    Object.keys(this.defaultOptions).forEach(e => {
        let t = n.attributes.getNamedItem(e);
        if (null != t) switch (t.name.toLowerCase()) {
            case "ltype":
                {
                    let n = this.getValidListingTypes(t.value);
                    null != n && (r[e] = n);
                    break
                }
            case "ptype":
                {
                    let n = this.getValidPropertyTypes(t.value);
                    null != n && (r[e] = n);
                    break
                }
            default:
                r[e] = t.value
        }
    }), this.createWidget(n, r)
}
```

I would like to use a hidden form like this below and get the it in my JS in the same format using a form with hidden inputs like below:

```
<form name="form1" id="form-search-widget">
  <input type="hidden" name="query" value="New York, NY">
  <input type="hidden" name="leadto" value="email@email.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="myid" value="5555">
</form>
```

Comment: So what is the issue? Select the form elements and loop over it.

Comment: Right so Im struggling with getting the data in there exactly as I am with custom tags the same way by getting the LI. IE, query="New York, NY" rsp="5555" leadto="email@email.com"

Comment: document.form1.query.value, document.form1. leadto.value, document.form1. myid.value,

Comment: Instead of looping over attributes you loop over the elements, read the name and value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So select the elements and loop over it. Here I use querySelectorAll and reduce

```js
const  hiddenElems = document.querySelectorAll('#form-search-widget input[type="hidden"]')

const data = Array.from(hiddenElems).reduce( function (obj, elem) {
  obj[elem.name] = elem.value
  return obj
}, {})

console.log(data)
```

```html
<form name="form1" id="form-search-widget">
  <input type="hidden" name="query" value="New York, NY">
  <input type="hidden" name="leadto" value="email@email.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="myid" value="5555">
</form>
```